# Printer Resolution is negative returned as negative

Tags: c#, printing

I am accessing the resolution of the default printer using the `PrintDocument`. The problem is that i am getting the

> PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X;
>   PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Y;

as negative values.

What is the possible problem of behind this? I've tested it with some other printers(by setting it as default) and gave non negative values. 
When i checked the registry entries pertaining to the printer which is giving negative resolution in the code. I've  seen `printMaxResolutionSupported` missing. Is this the potential problem? . For those cases i am not getting correct values i have included the code to set it to 600. will there be a problem because of this,

Comment: Did you check the `Kind` field of the `PrinterResolution` property? I believe the X/Y values are only actually used if it is `PrinterResolutionKind.Custom`. If `Kind` is one of the other values, the X/Y should theoretically be ignored.

Comment: yes, it is Low. what modifications should i do to get values.

Comment: If the resolution kind is one of the other values (High/Medium/Low/Draft) the printer (driver) will use its own corresponding predefined resolution. I don't think there is an easy way to actually *read* those values; maybe you should re-think your approach? Why do you even need them? On the other hand, if you make sure to set the resolution to Custom, then providing your own DPI values should work.

Comment: I'm writing a custom print preview. In order to draw it correctly, i need to know the DPI the printer is set to. If `Kind` is not `Custom` then I can't figure out how to determine the DPI...